# Difficulty writing text to new file in C#, root path error, access denied

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, streamwriter, access-denied

I am trying to write text to a file in my visual studio project. If the file does not exist I want to create it in the project.

When I try to implement the method that writes the text to the new file, the following error occurs:

> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the
>   path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\ErrorLog' is denied.

Seeing as though the root path will be different on each computer where the program is installed, how do I ensure this method can/will create a new text file in the user's project? (without knowing the root URL).

The method, that when called, should write text to a file.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Logs a message to a file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="msg">
    /// The message.
    /// </param>
    public void LogMessageToFile(string message)
    {
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("ErrorLog");
        tw.WriteLine(message);
        tw.Close();
    }
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please share the method's code.

Comment: If you create a file with no path, it will be created in the execution path folder, the folder where the Exe file resides.

Comment: Run the program as an Administrator ;) This might be the solution.

Comment: That is a good suggestion I hadn't really thought about it until now, but I do need to be able to do it on a non-administrative account.

Comment: Why don't you write to the %AppData% folder which is the logical place for Application Data and where you don't need administrator rights to write and which will be the same for all machines?

Comment: How do I write to that folder?

Comment: Is it simply TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("%AppData%"); ?

Comment: Is this an web project or a desktop application?

Comment: Web project. I am trying to write errors to the file, which I will then send the administrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a Web Project (ASP.NET) then you should write your log file in the standard folders provided they exists under your root site folder. By default you are unable to write outside the root folder for security reasons

```
public void LogMessageToFile(string message)
{
    // Get the physical path corresponding to the root folder of your site plus APP_DATA
    string appData = Server.MapPath("~/APP_DATA");

    // Create the log file name
    string logFile = Path.Combine(appData, "ErrorLog.txt");

    // Append to the log file and close/dispose the stream
    using(StreamWriter aw = new StreamWriter(logFile, true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

The folder APP_DATA under your root folder is used when read/write permissions are required by your code (database files, log files and other data files).
Notice also that a StreamWriter should be enclosed in the using statement to ensure proper closing in the eventuality of an exception or other write problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, suddenly, though it was working fine. After some checking and trying, it turned out that the antivirus software was the cause of this problem: access denied to file. I stopped the antivirus, temporarily, and no more access denied no matter what is the location of the file.